# Why can't I load the original style after I add a media query for desktop?

Tags: css, media-queries

Firstly, I created style for Mobile view and here is the CSS.

```css
.content>.hello{
 font-size: 6vw;
 color: white;
}
```

After that I change some style for desktop view

```css
@media only screen and (min-width:600px){
  .content>.hello{
    margin-top: 40px;;
 font-size: 5vw;
}
```

So, now when I uploaded the CSS to the server, I can see the **media query works well on my laptop**.When I resize my browser, it works well. But the problem is after I check the website on my phone, the media query also applied there. It supposed to have font size of 6vw on the phone.

Comment: When you inspect (in responsive mode) the element on your desktop, what does it show for the applied styles?

Comment: you mean inspect my media query mode on my desktop? It works well as expected, the font size is 5vw

Answer (score 1):

Okay, it is solved. I added this meta viewport.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

and i forgot to update the html file to the server. Took me hours for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

When I reduce the width of my browser window, I can see the font size changing.

Isn't that a cache problem ?

Is the phone screen really less than 600 pixels ?

I got into the habit in my link tags of introducing an unnecessary parameter, but   I can change its value each time I modify the stylesheet.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href=".../styles.css?v=17"/>
```

Comment: There is no problem on desktop, it works as expected. But its not working on mobile phone. Also whenever I changed my general rule/style for mobile, they are not applied since my mobile shows the media query which is supposed for desktop.

And my phone is Iphone 8 Plus

Answer (score -1):

The thing is that you have two rules:

## General rule

```
.content>.hello{
    font-size: 6vw;
    color: white;
}
```

This is applied to all devices.

## Desktop rule

```
@media only screen and (min-width:600px){
  .content>.hello{
    margin-top: 40px;;
    font-size: 5vw;
}
```

This is applied to desktop

## Possible problems

- since the rules have the same selector, therefore they have the same priority, in the case of desktop the one which runs later applies. You will need to either put the general rule before the media query, or transform your general rule to a media query of its own
- your phone might have a width of 600px or more, you will need to check the dimensions of the phone in pixels as well

Comment: For the first problem, yup I put the media query after the general rule. And i use Iphone 8 plus which i have checked the width is not over 600px.

Comment: On my desktop, it works well for desktop rule and when i resize my browser window smaller than 600px it applies general rule. However, on my mobile phone, it applies desktop rule.

Answer (score -1):

i just try, how about this :

```css
.content>.hello{
  font-size: 6vw;
  color:white;
  background-color:black;
}

@media screen and (max-width:600px){
 .content>.hello{
    font-size:5vw;
    margin-top:50px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
<div class="hello">
lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
</div>
</div>
```